# How do I count how many albums I have per decade?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, music

I'd like to know if I have more albums from the 70's than from the 80's, but I can't find any tool which can actually show me a list of albums or give me a count based on metadata.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Does anybody know of tool or command-line-fu which will help?

Comment: So after looking a bit more I came up with a solution:

In Banshee a smart playlist can be defined so it only contains songs from your collection that are at least from a certain year, and under another certain year. This fills the playlist with all songs that match the requirements.

Comment: then type that as an answer.  you can answer your own questions... it's allowed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Banshee a smart playlist can be defined so it only contains songs from your collection that are at least from a certain year, and under another certain year. This fills the playlist with all songs that match the requirements.